# PWABuilder WEB Browser

Tags: manifoldjs, pwabuilder

Good day.
I have little knowledge regarding codes.
I want the PWA to be downloaded when people enter the page from the phone or computers.
What should I do in PWABuilder?

Answer (score 1):

In case you haven't got the answer for this. 
Once you are on https://www.pwabuilder.com/
Follow the steps provided on the website, At the end of the step, You can download some files that you need to upload to your server.

So, this is clear that at least you have access to your server to upload the files. 
After you upload the files from https://www.pwabuilder.com/ to your server, ever user who visit your website will be prompted to have PWA of your website installed or "add to home" So, I hope this is simple enough to explain the process.